# $f \in \mathbb{C}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ and its zeroes

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Given a polynomial $f \in \mathbb{C}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$, then how can I prove that  $f(a_1,\ldots,a_n) = 0$ implies $f$ is a summation of factors of $x_i - a_i$ for $i \in \{1,\ldots, n\}?$

This is not at all obvious to me. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: It's not hard to show that $(x_1-a_1,\ldots,x_n-a_n)$ is maximal in $\mathbb{C}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$. But, the ideal of functions vanishing at $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ is a proper ideal containing $(x_1-a_1,\ldots,x_n-a_n)$ and thus the two ideals must actually be equal.

Comment: I don't remember exactly but, this question is already asked and it is answered by Mr.Alex Youcis...

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/500153/proving-that-kernels-of-evaluation-maps-are-generated-by-the-x-i-a-i/500167#comment1074479_500167 this might be helpful to you...