# Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $a_1, \dots, a_n$ elements of $R$. Prove that $\frac{R[x_1, \dots, x_n]}{(x_1-a_1, \dots, x_n-a_n)} \cong R.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, proof-writing, ring-isomorphism

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $a_1, \dots, a_n$ elements of $R$. Prove that $$\frac{R[x_1, \dots, x_n]}{(x_1-a_1, \dots, x_n-a_n)} \cong R.$$

We can look at this as
\begin{align*}
\frac{R[x_1, \dots, x_n]}{(x_1-a_1, \dots, x_n-a_n)} &\cong \frac{R[x_1]\cdots[x_n]}{(x-a_1, \dots, x-a_n)}\\
&\cong \frac{R[x_1]\cdots[x_n]/(x_n-a_n)}{(x-a_1, \dots, x-a_{n-1})}\\
&\cong \frac{R[x_1]\cdots[x_{n-1}]}{(x-a_1, \dots, x-a_{n-1})}\\
&\cong\\
&\ \ \vdots\\
&\cong R.
\end{align*}

---

However, I want to use an explicit map $\varphi: R[x_1, \dots, x_n] \twoheadrightarrow R$ where $f(x_1, \dots, x_n) \mapsto f(a_1, \dots, a_n)$ and show $\ker \varphi = (x_1-a_1, \dots, x_n-a_n)$.

I can see $(x_i-a_i) \mapsto 0$ for $1 \le i \le n$ and so $(x_1-a_1, \dots, x_n-a_n) \subset \ker \varphi$.

> **How can I show that if $f(a_1, \dots, a_n) =0$, then $f(x_1, \dots, x_n) \in (x_1-a_1, \dots, x_n-a_n)$?**

Comment: (Up to an automorphism $x \mapsto x+a$) you can assume $a=(0,\ldots,0)$ then $f(0,\ldots,0)$ is the constant coefficient, if it is $0$ then $f \in (x_1,\ldots,x_n)$. Otherwise $(x_1-a_1,\ldots,x_n-a_n)$ is a maximal ideal thus the kernel can't contain anything more.

Comment: @reuns $(x_1-a_1,...,x_n-a_n)$ is certainly not maximal if $R$ is not a field!

Comment: As what reuns suggested, WLOG, you can assume $a=(0,\dots, 0)$. Then $R[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ is free over $R$ with a basis $x_i$'s products. Now you have to show $f(0)$ contains no constant term which is exactly $f(0)=0$ giving.

Comment: @KevinCarlson Maximal in those ideals compatible with the free R-module structure

Comment: Do the answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1854588/ker-phi-a-1-a-n-for-a-ring-homomorphism-phi-rx-1-x-n-t?rq=1) answer your question?