# Correspondence between maximal ideals and solutions of the equations

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Assume we have a commutative algebra $A$ over a an algebraiclly closed field F of characteristic zero defined by generators  $x_1, \dots, x_n$ and relations:

$f_1=0$

$f_2=0$

$f_3 =0$

where $f_1$, $f_2$, and $f_3$ are in $x_1, \dots, x_n$.

That means $A=F[x_1, \dots, x_n]/(f_1, f_2, f_3)$.

my question:

Is true that if we want to find all maximal ideals of $A$, we need to solve the system of equations:

$f_1=0$

$f_2=0$

$f_3 =0$

and why?

Can someone help me to understand this correspondence?

Comment: Do you know the [Nullstellensatz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_Nullstellensatz)?

Comment: Yes, I know this theorm (If $F$ is an algebrically closed field and $I$ is a maximal ideal of $F[x_1, \dots, x_n]$  then $I=(x_1-a_1, \dots, x_n-a_n)$  for some  $a_i  \in F$. But I don't know how to apply this for my question. Can you please give detailed answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $I = (f_1, f_2, f_3)$. By the correspondence theorem, the maximal ideals of $A$ are exactly the (reductions of) maximal ideals $\DeclareMathOperator{\m}{\mathfrak{m}} \m \subseteq F[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ with $\m \supseteq I$. As you say, by the Weak Nullstellensatz the maximal ideals of $F[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ are all of the form $(x_1 - a_1, \ldots, x_n - a_n)$, so $\m = (x_1 - a_1, \ldots, x_n - a_n)$ for some $a_1, \ldots, a_n \in F$. Now $I \subseteq \m \iff f_i \in \m$ for all $i = 1,2,3$ and
$$
f_i \in (x_1 - a_1, \ldots, x_n - a_n) \iff f_i(a_1, \ldots, a_n) = 0 \, .
$$
(For details, see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1854588/ker-phi-a-1-a-n-for-a-ring-homomorphism-phi-rx-1-x-n-t/1854706#1854706).) Thus the maximal ideals of $A$ are exactly the reductions of the ideals $(x_1 - a_1, \ldots, x_n - a_n)$ such that
$$
f_1(a_1, \ldots, a_n) = f_2(a_1, \ldots, a_n) = f_3(a_1, \ldots, a_n) = 0 \, .
$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but what do you mean by “ the reductions” of the ideals?

Comment: Their reductions mod $I$, i.e., the image $\pi(\mathfrak{m})$ under the quotient map $\pi: F[x_1, \ldots, x_n] \to F[x_1, \ldots, x_n]/I$.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand. If we take algebra A=K[x,y]/xy with K is algebraically closed. Then I= (xy) and  the two solutions for  f=xy are x=0, y=a and x= b, y=0 where a and b are arbitrary complex numbers. Hence, the maximal ideals of A are (x,y-a)+I and (x-b,y)+I.(Do we write the maximal ideals in this way? or how?

Comment: @user130281 Yes, that's right.