# Finding maximal ideals in an artinian ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, artinian

Consider the ring $R:=\mathbb{C}[x,y]/\langle x^2-y^3, 4y^2-5x^2y+x^4\rangle$. I want to do the following:

1. Show that $R$ is artinian and calculate the maximal ideals $\mathfrak{m}$ of $R$. How many ideals there are?
2. Calculate the dimension of $R$ and $R_\mathfrak{m}$ as complex vector spaces.

I think it could be useful the following facts:

- $R$ is noetherian (but I am not sure why the Krull dimension of $R$ is $0$)
- $(x^2-y^3)$ is prime ideal of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$. Actually, there is an isomorphims between $\mathbb{C}[t]$ and $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/\langle x^2-y^3\rangle$ such that $\overline{x}\mapsto t^3$ and $\overline{y}\mapsto t^2$.
- $R$ has finitely many maximal ideals.

So, I am not certain how to calculate explicitly such ideals and dimensions. I aprreciate your ideas.

Comment: To prove its Krull dimension is $0$, you might be able to use that $\mathbb C[x,y]/(x^2-y^3)\cong\mathbb C[t]$ has Krull dimension $1$.

Comment: I think you can use the relation $y^3-x^2=0$ to plug into $4y^2+x^4-5x^2y$

Comment: Like $4^2+^4−5^2 =y^2(y-2)(y+2)(y-1)(y+1)$

Comment: Let $x/y=t$, you have $t^2=x^2/y^2=y$ and $t^3=x$

Comment: Then you will get something like $\mathbb{C}[t]/(t^4(t^2-2)(t^2+2)(t^2-1)(t^2+1))$. Then the rest is obvious.

Comment: The rings $\Bbb C[t]$ and $\Bbb C[x,y]/\langle x^2-y^3\rangle$ are not isomorphic. Indeed the first is normal while the second is not.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3903333/correspondence-between-maximal-ideals-and-solutions-of-the-equations/3905323)

Comment: Thank you for your comments. With these I can conclude that the $\mathbb{C}$-dimension of $A$ is 12 and there are nine maximal ideals. ¿Is it right?